# Do Transformers ever transform with people on board?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series

Are there any parts of the movies where Transformers transform with people in them?

If so, can you point out which scenes (and/or time) they are in and which movie.

The reason I'd like to put this together is to confirm whether or not Transformers can do this, since I was under the impression that they do not do this.

Comment: This happens several times, in face it happens in the first film.

Comment: @Edlothiad cool that's a start. will try find it

Comment: In fact*. I'm trying to see if a complete list exists because I don't exactly have the time to watch 5 films ;) It looks like I lied. They never transform with the person inside as otherwise, */*squish**. But they in fact toss them out and catch them again while moving.

Comment: @Edlothiad that would be cool. kinda what i was hoping for here if it isn't anywhere

Comment: Here is an [example of Sam being tossed out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfYoRKLzJXw)

Comment: @Edlothiad nice

Comment: [Second example](https://youtu.be/fWvMxhX35Lo?t=21m). Now I have no reason to believe that they couldn't except for these two examples suggesting they wouldn't.

Comment: I think this happens once in the most recent film The Last Knight.

Comment: Not the movies but in Transformers Prime Bulkhead transforms from vehicle to robot with Miko inside. Transformation around 13s, realization that Miko was there around 55s. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNdzJF7JMu0

Comment: Obligatory link: http://pbfcomics.com/comics/disassemble/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Hah, they did a spoof of that in robot chicken ( or a similar show, can't find it) aswell, just a lot more graphic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Dark of the Moon, there was the slow motion moment on the highway chase scene where Bumblebee not only transforms, but ejects Sam out of his vehicle as he did so. He then transformed around Sam afterwards.

In Age of Extinction there was another slow motion with Cade, Tessa and Shane being ejected from Bumblebee as he transformed and basically tossed them to Optimus, who transformed around them.

In the Last Knight, Hot Rod transformed and ejected Vivian.

And also (somewhat transforming), Cade and Vivian were inside of Bumblebee and he used his guns against Barricade.

(Not in the movies)
In Prime, both Bulkhead and Wheeljack had transformed with Miko inside, though not noticing/remembering at first.

In Rescue Bots, Heatwave transformed with Kade still inside on purpose because Kade made him a bit angry.